# When does it suffice to show statements about rings only for the local ring after localizing at a prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I'm learning commutative Algebra with the book from Eisenbud.
But I'm having trouble understanding some of his Proofs. 
Often we have a Statement about a ring R or an R-module M, which we'd like to proof. Then he assumes wlog that R is a local ring and continues proving the Statement. Now I know the fact, that if $p\subset R$ is a prime, then $R_p$, its localization at p, is a local ring. But I don't know why it suffices to show the Statement for $R_p$ instead of R. I could give you examples, but this 'trick' is used in very different settings, so I'd rather have a general answer about when it is reasonable to make this reduction and when it is not.

Comment: Usually the "wlog" part is not justified, because the author assumes that it's easy: what this means is that when the author says "we may assume $R$ is local", what they actually say is "if we know the statement for all $R_p$, we can deduce it for $R$". So it is reasonable to make this reduction when you see a way to prove the statement for $R$ from its validity for the $R_p$'s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I love this question.

Secondly, as Max says in the comments, what needs to be true in order to use this trick is that the statement "Property A holds for ring $R$ (or module $M$)" needs to follow from the statement "Property A holds for all localizations $R_p$ (or $M_p$), as $p$ ranges over all primes of $R$." Properties of which this is true are said to be *local properties*. Some properties are local by definition, i.e. the definition is first given for local rings and then *defined* to hold for general rings whenever it holds for every localization (e.g. the notion of a *[regular ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ring)*), but other properties' localness requires a theorem.

For example, injectivity is a local property of a map: If $\phi: M\rightarrow N$ is a module homomorphism over a ring $R$, and for every prime $p\triangleleft R$, we have $\phi_p:M_p \rightarrow N_p$ is injective, then $\phi$ is injective. This statement requires proof (it is Proposition 3.9 in Atiyah-MacDonald's classic *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* and I'm sure it's also proven in Eisenbud), but once we have proved it, it means we can afterward assess injectivity just by considering localizations.

Comment: Yes the point is, that I didn't see many of these properties.
For example R=0 iff $R_p=0$ for any (associated) prime p.
And i saw this property about Maps you mentioned.
(this is also true if I replace injective by surjective if I remember correctly.)
But i didn't see more properties that behave like that than these two.

Comment: I have a copy of Eisenbud so if there is a particular proof you want to point to I can have a look?